# Reg Expression in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string like this '102/103/104/106'

Now if i pass 102 as input then output should be the next field that is 103. if 103 then output should be 104 and if 106 then output should be null(as for last field I don't have any further expression). I can do this using procedure by splitting the string into arrays and comparing. But can I do this through sql statement something like this

```
select '102/103/104/106' from dual where [expression 102 or 103].
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
-- p_whole_string = '102/103/104/106'
-- p_prev = '102'
select 
  regexp_substr(p_whole_string, '(^|/)' || p_prev || '/([^/]+)', 1, 1, null, 2) 
  as next
from dual;
```

Added NVL to return last value if 106 is entered:

```
SELECT NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR('102/103/104/106', '(^|/)' || '106' || '/([^/]+)', 1, 1, null, 2), REGEXP_SUBSTR('102/103/104/106', '[^/]+$')) as nxt
  FROM dual
/
```

Comment: Privet Egor, your example is the best. But if I enter 106 then result is null. You may modify it to return 106 to be perfect.

Comment: @Art - This can be done easily: `nvl(..., regexp_substr(p_whole_string, '[^/]+$'))`

Comment: I think you should add it to your example. This is what I meant.

Comment: @Art : `Sushant Butta = Art` ?

Comment: @@Egor-you are very suspicious... I will modify your example myself. And Art is Art from Tashkent, but lives and works in USA: arturb33@hotmail.com

Comment: @Art - OP wishes that `if 106 then output should be null`

Comment: @@Egor - others need to learn too, including me. This way you have both examples, with and w/out NVL. You can remove my edits and modify it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @@Egor, your answer is best. Can you help me out in understanding this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in pure SQL with something like this:

```
--convert your string into rows
with vals as (
select
       substr('102/103/104/106', 
              instr('102/103/104/106', '/', 1, level)-3, 
              3
             ) col,
       level lvl
from dual
connect by level <= length('102/103/104/106')-length(replace('102/103/104/106', '/'))+1
)
select * 
from   (
select col, 
       lead(col) over (order by lvl) next_val -- find the next value in the list 
from   vals
)
where  col = :val;
```

Basically, convert your string into rows by parsing it. Then use the analytic `lead` to find the "next" value.

Answer (score 1):

works for Oracle form 10 up.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('102/103/104/106', '(^|/)102/[^/]+'), -- returns 102/103
  '[^/]+',1,2) val -- takes second part
FROM DUAL;
```

with parameters looks like this:

```
-- p_string_to_search = '102/103/104/106'
-- p_string_to_match = '102'

SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_string_to_search, '(^|/)' || p_string_to_match ||'/[^/]+'), -- returns 102/103
  '[^/]+',1,2) val -- takes second part
FROM DUAL;
```